# How to pass parameters to Vue.js i18n <i18n-t> tag

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I'm using the vue.js i18n package and more specifically, the i18n-t tag to do a translation, but I cannot find anywhere in the documentation how can I pass parameters?
Here is the tag...

```
  <i18n-t :keypath="title" scope="parent">
  </i18n-t>
```

Normally I pass the parameters using v-t notation...

```
  v-t="{ path: title, args: { param1: 'value' } }
```

But I use the component as it is the only way I found so far to access the translations in the parent scope...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your translation with param is something like:

```
messages: {
  en: {
    title: 'Some {value} title.',
  }
}
```

you can try with [slots syntax](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/component.html#slots-syntax-usage):

```
<i18n-t keypath="title" tag="p">
  <template v-slot:value>
    <span>{{ myValue }}</span>
  </template>
</i18n-t>
```

Comment: I didnt fully understand this syntax but I do now! Thanks a lot again!!!!